# Accessing the Forge Viewer From Two HTML Files

Tags: javascript, html, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have been working on a website incorporating the autodesk-forge viewer (more details can be seen on my past questions). I have successfully made many autodesk-forge viewer functions in a standard javascript (.js) file. These functions include displaying the viewer, and isolating to a particular part, when an external button is pressed.
Currently I have a main html/php home page where I have included my javascript file with all my forge functions using `<script src="MyForgeFunctions.js"></script>`
These functions are accessed through a button, which successfully displays the viewer in the html page. Attached to my main php/html page, another html/php page was added through an iframe html reference (`<iframe src="URL.php"></iframe>`). My home page displays the main machines we make, while the embedded php/html page displays all the stations within the machine. I have also included the MyForgeFunctions.js inside this second php/html page. Because of the way the website is set up, I need to be able to access the viewer in both web pages. However, when I attempt to access the viewer from the second html page, I get a message that the viewer is undefined. Below is my code from MyForgeFunctions.js.

```
var ext = '';
var dim = '';
var assemblyname = '';

function getAssemblyName(){
assemblyname = sessionStorage.getItem("assemblyName");
//var ext = partname.substr(partname.lastIndexOf('.'));
ext = assemblyname.split('.');
dim = ext[0] + ':1';
console.log(assemblyname);
console.log(dim);
if (dim !== ''){
    isolateSelected();
}
}



//function to get part name from __MachineParts.php
var partname = '';
var extension = '';
var namewithoutextension = '';
function getPartName(){
partname = sessionStorage.getItem("partName");
//var ext = partname.substr(partname.lastIndexOf('.'));
extension = partname.split('.');
namewithoutextension = extension[0] + ':1'
console.log(partname);
console.log(namewithoutextension);
if (namewithoutextension !== ''){
    isolateSelectedPart();
}
}



/*******************************************************************************
 * 
 * AUTODESK FORGE VIEWER CODE (HTTP REQUESTS)
 * 
 *******************************************************************************/
//VARIABLE DECLARATION

var code = '';
var access_token = '';
const hub = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
const project ='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
const folder='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
const item = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
var itemid = '';
var urn = '';
var urn2 = '';

//allow the program to view data from autodesk
function authorize(){
    window.location.href = "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&scope=data:read data:write bucket:read viewables:read bucket:create data:create";
}

//grab the code from the url
function getCode(){
    const querystring = window.location.search;
   // console.log(querystring);
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(querystring);
    code = urlParams.get('code');
   // console.log(code);
}
//call the function to get the code right away, and obtain a token
getCode();
getToken();

//function to obtain access token
function getToken(){
    $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/gettoken',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    data:'client_id=dm2VLfnwJ6rYHKPAg7dG6l9yVbBQPGlH&client_secret=HRMpOPusLhsVoIMk&grant_type=authorization_code&code=' + code + '&redirect_uri=http://team/__MachineViewerMV.php',

    success:function(response){
       // console.log(response);
        access_token = response.access_token;
        console.log(access_token);
    }
})
}

//Grab desired file id from project folder
function getItem(){
    $.ajax({
        method:'GET',
        url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/' + project + '/folders/' + item + '/contents',
        headers:{
            Authorization:'Bearer ' + access_token
        },
    /*  beforeSend:function(before){
            if(access_token !== '' && viewer !==''){
            destroyViewer();}
        },*/
        success:function(response){
           //console.log(response);
           // folder = response.data[0].id;
           // console.log(folder);
         //  itemid = response.data[0].id;
           //console.log(itemid);
           console.log(response);

           for (var i = 0; i<response.data.length; i++){
               //console.log(response.data[i].attributes.displayName);
               if(response.data[i].attributes.displayName == fileName){
                   //console.log('hooray');
                  itemid = response.data[i].id;
                   console.log(itemid);
                   getVersion();
                   break;
               }
               else if (response.data[i].attributes.displayName !== fileName){
                   itemid = '';
               }
           }

        },
        error:function(error){
            authorize();
        }
    })
}

function get2dItem(){
    $.ajax({
        method:'GET',
        url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/' + project + '/folders/' + item + '/contents',
        headers:{
            Authorization:'Bearer ' + access_token
        },
        /*beforeSend:function(before){
            if(access_token !== '' && viewer !== ''){
            destroyViewer();}
        },*/
        success:function(response){
           //console.log(response);
           // folder = response.data[0].id;
           // console.log(folder);
         //  itemid = response.data[0].id;
           //console.log(itemid);
           console.log(response);

           for (var i = 0; i<response.data.length; i++){
               //console.log(response.data[i].attributes.displayName);
               if(response.data[i].attributes.displayName == fileName2d){
                   //console.log('hooray');
                  itemid = response.data[i].id;
                   console.log(itemid);
                   getVersion();
                   break;
               }
               else if (response.data[i].attributes.displayName !== fileName2d){
                   itemid = '';
               }
           }

        },
        error:function(error){
            authorize();
        }
    })
}


//get version of the file using its id
function getVersion(){
    $.ajax({
        method:'GET',
        url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/' + project + '/items/' + itemid + '/versions',
        headers:{
            Authorization:'Bearer ' + access_token
        },
        success:function(response){
           //console.log(response);
           urn = btoa(response.data[0].relationships.storage.data.id);
           console.log(urn);
           translateToSVF();
        }
    })
}

function translateToSVF(){
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url:"https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job",

        headers:{
            "content-type": "application/json",
            Authorization: "Bearer " + access_token
        },
        data:JSON.stringify({
            "input":{ "urn":urn

            },
            "output": {
     "formats": [
       {
         "type": "svf",
         "views": [
           "2d",
           "3d"
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
        }),
        success:function(response){
          //  console.log(response);
            urn2 = response.urn;
            console.log(urn2);
            checkStatus();
        }
    })
}

function checkStatus(){
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/" + urn2 + "/manifest",
        headers:{
            Authorization: "Bearer " + access_token
        },
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            if (response.progress == 'complete'){
               displayViewer();
            }
            else if (response.progress !== 'complete'){
                alert('File Still Uploading, Press the Display Button Again!');
            }
            }

    })
}

//function to get list of viewables\
var guid = '';
function getViewable(){
    $.ajax({
        method:'GET',
        headers:{
            Authorization: "Bearer " + access_token
        },
        url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/' + urn2 + '/metadata',
    success:function(response){
        console.log(response);
        guid = response.data.metadata[0].guid;
        console.log(guid);
    }

    })
}

//funciton to get the list of items within a model
function getTree(){
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        headers:{
            Authorization: "Bearer " + access_token
        },
        url:'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/' + urn2 + '/metadata/' + guid + '/properties',
        success:function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    })
}



/**********************************************************************************
 * 
 * FUNCTION TO DISPLAY THE VIEWER IN THE HTML PAGE
 * 
 **********************************************************************************/

 var viewer;

 function displayViewer(){
    //var viewer;
var options = {
    env: 'AutodeskProduction',
    api: 'derivativeV2',  // for models uploaded to EMEA change this option to 'derivativeV2_EU'
    getAccessToken: function(onTokenReady) {
        var token = access_token;
        console.log(token);
        var timeInSeconds = 3600; // Use value provided by Forge Authentication (OAuth) API
        onTokenReady(token, timeInSeconds);
    }
};

Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function() {

    var htmlDiv = document.getElementById('forgeViewer');
    viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv);
    var startedCode = viewer.start();
   // sessionStorage.setItem("viewer", viewer);
    if (startedCode > 0) {
        console.error('Failed to create a Viewer: WebGL not supported.');
        return;
    }

    console.log('Initialization complete, loading a model next...');

});
var documentId = 'urn:'+urn2;
Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);

function onDocumentLoadSuccess(viewerDocument) {
    var defaultModel = viewerDocument.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
    viewer.loadDocumentNode(viewerDocument, defaultModel);
    console.log(viewer);


}

function onDocumentLoadFailure() {
    console.error('Failed fetching Forge manifest');
}

}

//function to hide the viewer
function destroyViewer(){
    console.log(viewer);
    viewer.finish();
viewer = null;
Autodesk.Viewing.shutdown();
}

/*****************************************************************************
 * FUNCTIONS TO MODIFY THE VIEWER TO ZOOM INTO THE CORRECT PART/ASSEMBLY
 */



function isolateSelected(){
    console.log(dim);
    console.log(viewer);
    viewer.search(dim, function(dbIds) {
   // viewer.search('"' + 'M-109408 FOLDING PLOUGH:2' + '"', function(dbIds) {
        console.log(dbIds.length);
        getSubset(dbIds, 'label', dim, function(dbIds) {
       // getSubset(dbIds, 'label', 'M-109408 FOLDING PLOUGH:2', function(dbIds) {
       // getSubset(dbIds, property.name, 'M-54439 POST TUBING:1', function(dbIds) {
            //getSubset(dbIds, property.name, property.value, function(dbIds){
            var it = viewer.model.getData().instanceTree;
            //console.log(it);
           for (i = 0; i<dbIds.length; i++){
               var namepart = it.getNodeName(dbIds[i]);
               if (namepart !== undefined){
            console.log(dbIds);
            console.log(namepart);}}
          /*  for (i = 121; i<381;i++){
                var dbId = i;
            var it = NOP_VIEWER.model.getData().instanceTree;
            var name = it.getNodeName(dbId);
            console.log(name);}*/
            viewer.isolate(dbIds)
           viewer.select(dbIds);
            viewer.utilities.fitToView();
        })
    }, function(error) {})
}

function isolateSelectedPart(){
    console.log(namewithoutextension);
    viewer.search(namewithoutextension, function(dbIds) {
   // viewer.search('"' + 'M-109408 FOLDING PLOUGH:2' + '"', function(dbIds) {
        console.log(dbIds.length);
        getSubset(dbIds, 'label', namewithoutextension, function(dbIds) {
       // getSubset(dbIds, 'label', 'M-109408 FOLDING PLOUGH:2', function(dbIds) {
       // getSubset(dbIds, property.name, 'M-54439 POST TUBING:1', function(dbIds) {
            //getSubset(dbIds, property.name, property.value, function(dbIds){
            var it = viewer.model.getData().instanceTree;
            //console.log(it);
           for (i = 0; i<dbIds.length; i++){
               var namepart = it.getNodeName(dbIds[i]);
               if (namepart !== undefined){
            console.log(dbIds);
            console.log(namepart);}}
          /*  for (i = 121; i<381;i++){
                var dbId = i;
            var it = NOP_VIEWER.model.getData().instanceTree;
            var name = it.getNodeName(dbId);
            console.log(name);}*/
            viewer.isolate(dbIds)
           viewer.select(dbIds);
            viewer.utilities.fitToView();
        })
    }, function(error) {})
}

//function to find the dbid of the part/assembly
function getSubset(dbIds, name, value, callback) {
    console.log("getSubset, dbIds.length before = " + dbIds.length)
    viewer.model.getBulkProperties(dbIds, {
        propFilter: [name],
        ignoreHidden: true
    }, function(data) {
        var newDbIds = []
        for (var key in data) {
            var item = data[key]
           // console.log(item.properties);
            if (item.properties[0].displayValue === value) {
                newDbIds.push(item.dbId)
            }
        }

        console.log("getSubset, dbIds.length after = " + newDbIds.length)

        callback(newDbIds)

    }, function(error) {})
}
```

Because of how the webpage is set up, when I needed to use a variable from the second web page in the first, I used sessionStorage.getItem and sessionStorage.setItem. I have also made a simple function as so inside MyForgeFunctions.js:

```
function checkViewer(){
console.log(viewer);
}
```

I then included a button in both html pages to execute the function with an onclick event. When the function is run from the first/home html page the following is displayed:
`T {globalManager: e, clientContainer: div#forgeViewer, container: div.adsk-viewing-viewer.notouch.dark-theme.quality-text, config: {…}, contextMenu: o, …}`. Which is normal for the viewer, but when the function is executed from the second html page, the viewer is undefined. Any help as to why this is happening or any solutions will be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: post your code for the iframe page - iframe is independent from the parent page and you'd have very limited access to the elements on parent page due to security reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the iframe, in order to access the viewer inside the main web page, I had to use (parent.viewer).